# How do I create a function that returns the first non-nil, non-empty string passed to it?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to implement a function that returns the first non-blank string from the variables passed to it. Unfortunately, some of these variables might be nil, so the naive approach

```
function first_non_empty(...)
    for i, item in ipairs({...}) do
        if item ~= nil and item ~= '' then
            return item
        end
    end
    return ''
end
```

doesn't work: ipairs quits out as soon as it encounters a nil value. This can be fixed by changing the requirements so that the variables can't be nil, or by passing the length to the function so table length doesn't have to rely on `ipairs`, or by wrapping all parameters in a function so that none of them are explicitly nil

```
function first_non_empty_func(...)
    for i, func in ipairs({...}) do
        local item = func()
        if item ~= nil and item ~= '' then
            return item
        end
    end
    return ''
end

function fn(p)
    local f = function() return p end
    return f
end

-- change callers to first_non_empty_func(fn(a), fn(b), fn(c))
```

However, both of these solutions complicate the function prototype. Does there exist a function taking an ordered list of parameters, some of which may be nil, which returns the first of those parameters which is both non-nil and not an empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select('#', ...)` can be used to get the number of provided arguments, so here is an alternative that doesn't use `table.pack`:

```
function first_non_empty_pack(...)
    for i = 1, select('#', ...) do
        local item = select(i, ...)
        if item ~= nil and item ~= '' then
            return item
        end
    end
    return ''
end
```

Comment: Nice! As a bonus, as `select` is present on 5.1 while `table.pack` is not, I can use this with Scribunto.

Comment: @ChrisMidgley `function table.pack( ... )  return { n = select( '#', ... ), ... }  end` is all. For long vararg lists, repeatedly copying the list for the `select` call may be slower than creating a table once and iterating over that. In the other direction, creating tables that need to be garbage collected later may be slower. So benchmark to see which one is faster in your case (or just pick whichever one you think is cleaner until you see that speed is actually an issue).

Answer (score 4):

Use `table.pack`, which preserves all nil entries and returns the number of entries in the `n` field:

```
function first_non_empty_pack(...)
    local t = table.pack(...)
    for i = 1, t.n do
        local item = t[i]
        if item ~= nil and item ~= '' then
            return item
        end
    end
    return ''
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach is to use recursion. No extra tables created, etc:

```
function first_non_empty(item, ...)
    if item ~= nil and item ~= '' then return item end
    return first_non_empty(...)
end
```

But the list has to end with some ending marker. For example, boolean 'false', indicating there's no non-nil, nonempty strings.

Comment: An end marker is not needed, `select( '#', ... ) == 0` can be used as the stopping condition. An alternative that avoids repeated `select` calls is to determine the count first and then count down as in `do  local function rec(n,item,...) if item ~= nil and item ~= '' then  return item  elseif n > 0 then  return rec( n-1, ... )  end  end  function first_non_empty( ... )  return rec( select( '#', ... ), ... )  end end`.

Comment: Having ending marker makes this func faster and simpler. Also, ending marker can be not boolean, but some fallback string value, which should be returned when no other strings found. That saves some checks outside of this func. It all depends on actual needs, and this func is just one of choices :)